# CSS styling: tables with inside tables (borders and backgrounds)

Tags: html, css

Trying to build some webpages that contain various tables - e.g. main table that is holding a header - main page and a footer of a page - marked 2 on the picture.

In the main section of this table I have a lot of tables that shows various data for the user - marked 1 on the picture, so I have added specific style for this tables, it looks like this:

```
.datatable {
    border-collapse: collapse; /* hiding double lines between cells */
    border: 2px solid white; /* hiding border of a table */
}

.datatable th, td
{
     padding: 5px 10px;
     border: 1px solid black; /* adding a border for th and td */
}   

.datatable th {
    background-color: #EBECEC;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}    

.datatable tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #EBECEC;
}
```

And these tables, classed with .datatable works fine and seems it's ok. when showing it's in browser.

But table which contains this tables (2) with data inside (1) - also have some borders over it's cells. My css doesn't contain any directives referring properties of simple tables, and such tables were showed without any borders (border="0" property of a table tag).

How to fix it? How to control the properties of table 2?
it seems the browser gets the properties of .datatable class and applied it to table or td of the upper-level table (inheritance or some)..

The codepen is here: https://codepen.io/gzbqqfbl-the-encoder/pen/QWqrBxP

[image]

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: or paste a codepen

Comment: @Imanpal: **no**, this isn't an either/or; the OP can definitely add a link to an external demo site (such as CodePen, JS Fiddle or whatever), but the relevant "*[mcve]*" code *must* be in the question, otherwise there's likely insufficient information to answer the question and - in the event of link rot - future visitors may well struggle to understand the problem in the question and the relevance of any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Those borders belong to the first td in the first table so something like this (put at the end of the stylesheet to override anything else that might be inserted above)

```
table:first-child tr td:first-child { border: none;}
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Dietonline Service. Результаты расчета потребности в основных пищевых веществах и энергии </title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      background-color: White;
      font-family: rubik, sans-serif, san-serif;
      font-size: 14 px;
    }
    
    table.datatable {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      /* hiding double lines between cells */
      border: 2px solid white;
      /* hiding border of a table */
    }
    
    .datatable th,
    td {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      /* adding a border for th and td */
    }
    
    .datatable th {
      background-color: #EBECEC;
      font-weight: bold;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    .datatable tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #EBECEC;
    }
    
    h1,
    h2,
    h3 {
      color: #36CA36
    }
    
    a:link {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #36CA36;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #36CA36;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #FB6737;
    }
    
    a:active {
      text-decoration: underline;
      color: #36CA36;
    }
    
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      /* hiding double lines between cells */
      border: 0px solid grey;
      /* hiding border of a table */
    }
    
    table:first-child tr td:first-child {
      border: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <!--maintable-->
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- 6oo px center table -->
        <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" border="0" style="border">
          <tr>
            <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 20px 0 10px 0;">
              <img src="img/sample_logo.jpg" width="200" style="display: block;">
              <h3>Питание и Здоровье</h3>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <!--main content td-->
            <td style="padding: 10px 15px 20px 15px;">
              <h2>Результаты расчета индивидуальных потребностей основных пищевых веществ и энергии</h2>

              <!--provided data-->
              <table width=100% class="datatable">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan='2'>Данные, предоставленные пользователем для расчета</th< /tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Пол</td>
                      <td>женский</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Возраст</td>
                      <td>11</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Вес</td>
                      <td>60</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Коэффициент физической активности</td>
                      <td>1.4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Дополнительная информация</td>
                      <td>kid 6 year school</td>
                    </tr>
              </table><br /> <a href='new_query?'>Неверно указаны параметры? Проведите еще один расчет ...</a>
              <!--provided data end -->
              <h3>Результаты расчета</h3>
              <!-- proteins & energy table -->
              <table width="100%" class="datatable">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Суточная потребность в белках, жирах, углеводах и энергии</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Энергия, ккал</td>
                  <td>2400.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Белки, г</td>
                  <td>80.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Белки животного происхождения, г</td>
                  <td>57.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Жиры, г</td>
                  <td>78.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Углеводы, г</td>
                  <td>346.0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br />
              <!--proteins and energy table end-->
              <table width="100%" class="datatable">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Суточная потребность в минералах</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Кальций, мг</td>
                  <td>1200.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Фосфор, мг</td>
                  <td>1200.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Магний, мг</td>
                  <td>300.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Железо, мг</td>
                  <td>17.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Цинк, мг</td>
                  <td>12.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Йод, мкг</td>
                  <td>160.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Селен, мкг</td>
                  <td>55.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Медь, мг</td>
                  <td>1.8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Марганец, мг</td>
                  <td>0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Хром, мкг</td>
                  <td>0.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Молибден, мкг</td>
                  <td>0.0</td>
                </tr>
              </table><br />
              <table width="100%" class="datatable">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Суточная потребность в витаминах</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Витамин А, мкг РЕ</td>
                  <td>600.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Биотин, мкг</td>
                  <td>25.0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Пантотеновая кислота, мг</td>
                  <td>4.0</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br />
              <table width="100%" class="datatable">
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="2">Рекомендованные нормы потребления минорных и биологически активных веществ еды с установленным физиологическим действием на организм</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Каротиноиды, мг</td>
                  <td>15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Бета-каротин, мг</td>
                  <td>5</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <br />
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td bgcolor="#EBECEC" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
                &copy;Dietonline Service, 2022
              </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked for an external table but also changed properties of borders for .datatable - borders for the first row and first column disappeared.. see it in https://codepen.io/gzbqqfbl-the-encoder/pen/QWqrBxP, please but i need to keep that borders in .datatable but not to show them in external..